# how to give top property define in css for chrome or firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

```
I am facing the problem in css for different browser.
```

When i am change the CSS for "combi_toggle_bar" of top property. if it  top: -48px then it is showing no gap on Chrome browser but problem comes in Firefox browser. if top:-52px then it is showing no Gap on Firefox browser but chrome is showing gap. You can also see the screenshot.

Give Me solution How to fix this problem. I have attached Screenshot Both Browser.

```js
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".combi_search_btn").click(function(){
                $(".search-grid").toggle();
            });
        });
        </script>
```

```css
  .combi_toggle_bar{
          display: block;
            float: right;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 100;
            right:0px;
            top:-52px;
            -webkit-margin-top: -48px !important; /* for mozilla */
            -moz-margin-top: -52px !important; /* for mozilla */
            z-index: :9999;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    
        .combi_search_btn{
          border: none;
          float: right;
          background:#F1F1F2;
          border-radius:14px 14px 0 0;
          border:2px solid #BABABA;
          border-bottom:0px;
          padding:15px;
          color:#0A79AD;
          font-size:14px;
          font-weight:700;
          cursor:pointer;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="combi_toggle_bar">
    <button class="combi_search_btn">SEARCH FOR A PRODUCT +</button>
    </div>
```

```
Please See IT.[![Firefox Screenshot][1]][1]


[![Chrome Screenshot][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqqFb.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWYJ6.png
```

Comment: try adding a FIDDLE for the scenario.

Comment: You seem to be missing the screenshots you refer to.

Comment: Please open this link then you will see screenshot. 
  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EqqFb.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nWYJ6.png

Comment: How about `bottom:0` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below css, which will affect only for chrome

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
.combi_toggle_bar{
            top:-42px !important;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Arun Kumar..!!

Comment: I am facing the same problem in Firefox Browser On resolution 1920. It is oK on resolution 1366. Please Give me solution how to fix it by resolution on same browser.

Comment: Try this media query @media screen and (min-width:1366px) { css styles }

Comment: if i am using this media query then its minor effect on chrome browser.